# MySQL with Java: Open connection only if possible

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm running a database-heavy Java application on a cluster, using Connector/J 5.1.14. Therefore, I have up to 150 concurrent tasks accessing the same MySQL database. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

This happens because the server can't handle so many connections. I can't change anything on the database server. So my question is: Can I check if a connection is possible BEFORE I actually connect to the database?

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
check database for open connection slots
if (slot is free) {
    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
else {
    wait ...
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try{
    //try to connect
}catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException ex) {
    //what ever you want to do
}
```

**Also See :**

- [Connection Pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I embedded it in a while loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a connection pool like as for example [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). A bit decent connection pool can wait a certain timeout and retry a certain amount of times until a connection is available and then return it. Also ensure that you call `Connection#close()` in `finally` block of every `try` where you acquire the connection. Otherwise the connection is never released to pool (or to the database when you don't use a pool) and you will run out of them anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know C3P0. All my connections are closed, it's a cluster thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like should work better.

```
try 
{
    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
} 
catch ( com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnection e ) 
{
    // wait ...
}
```